# MATLAB no longer supports user-defined MEX configuration?

Tags: matlab, mex

I've upgraded my MATLAB to 2014b (on OS X 10.10), and tried to test some old MEX C/C++ codes.

As usual, I run `mex -setup` from the command window, and I would expect to be provided the chance to overwrite the option file "meshopt.sh".

But now, it seems MATLAB has made some change and I am not allowed to change the MEX configuration, it simply says:

> MEX configured to use Xcode with Clang for C language compilation,
>   ...
>   to choose a different language, select one from the following
>
> ```
> mex -setup C++
> mex -setup FORTRAN
> ```

So, is it true that the old ways to modify "mexopts.sh" are no longer feasible?

Comment: You can always check to see if the file is there in the `mex` directory of your MATLAB distribution once you choose one of these setups then modify the file that way.... but if this is seriously the case, then it's a crying shame.  I won't upgrade to 2014b then!

Comment: I'm still on R2014a so I can't verify myself, but can you try calling something like `mex -f my_mexopts.sh ...` where `my_mexopts.sh` is the configuration file from previous versions?

Comment: @Amro it says "An invalid options file name was specified".

Comment: @lorniper: you did replace `my_mexopts.sh` with the name of your actual config file, right?

Comment: @Amro, sure..anyway, disappointing..

Comment: Anyway MATLAB switched to using XML config files, so in theory you could customize those instead. Look in your preference folder `prefdir()` for files like `mex_C++_win64.xml` or the equivalent for OSX

Comment: @Amro Finally I found some workaround, it's strange that mathworks suggest "Using the 'mexsh -setup' command selects an options file that is
placed in /Users/user1/.matlab/R2014b", however, I don't even have the mexsh command on R2014b !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the following command works:

```
mex -setup my_mexopts.sh
```

however, there's some warning information,

**Legacy MEX infrastructure is provided for compatibility; it will be removed in a future version of MATLAB**.

Apart from that, everything looks fine, except I got some warning at compile time seems due to compiler version(gcc 4.9.1) on my current system(OS X 10.10).

**gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

When I run `mex -setup C`, I see information like the following:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 (C)  mex -setup:H:\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc2008.xml C
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (C)  mex -setup:H:\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc2010.xml C
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)  mex -setup:H:\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc2012.xml C
```

The `mex` part is actually a link you can click to choose that configuration.  So, to make your own:

1. Choose an xml as a template and copy it. (e.g I'd copy `H:\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc2012.xml` to `%AppData%\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014b\mex_C++_win64_custom.xml`).
2. Make the edits in the XML file, probably in the `<vars> tag` (e.g. modify `COMPFLAGS` or `CFLAGS` whatever variable has your compiler options) or the `<env>` tag (e.g. `PATH`, `INCLUDE`, `LIB`, etc.)
3. Set that to the current configuration:

   ```
   mex -setup:C:\[YourMATLABAppDataHere]\myCopts.xml C
   ```

Note that a good place in Windows to keep settings is under `%APPDATA%`.  For MATLAB R2014b, this would be something like `C:\Users\[yourname]\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014b`.

Do the same for C++ or FORTRAN configurations too.