# Legacy MEX infrastructure is provided for compatibility

Tags: matlab, compatibility, mex

There is this warning kind of message when compiling `mexFunction` files using the `mex` command in Matlab 2014b.

`Legacy MEX infrastructure is provided for compatibility; it will be removed in a future version of MATLAB.`

What is this supposed to mean? There comes a link with this message, but I did not find something useful. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426160/matlab-2014b-no-more-supports-user-defined-mex-configuration/26428849#26428849) did not make me more wise.

Will the MEX API vanish? Will there be a different interface? **What is going to change exactly?** Can anybody tell?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426160/

Comment: @nkjt yes, I linked that in the question, but that does not explain something, does it? *Apart from that, everything looks fine* - okay, right now. But what's going to change when *MEX infrastructure..will be removed*? Will Mex functions still be supported and will there be an interface to C/C++?

Comment: Mathworks will not remove the MEX interface, as many of their built-in functions rely on MEX. I assume you are using some deprecated functions or options. Without any information, one cannot say where the problem is. You can check the [Release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) for changes in the MEX interface. (See the *functionality being removed* section)

Comment: @hbaderts I see. So it just means that there is some `mx` function used, which is going to be removed. Could have made the hint more  precise.

Comment: It just means you won't be able to configure with a mexopts.bat in the future.  You'll have to use XML.

Comment: @chappjc Now I got it, thx. That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Ok, in that case I made an answer.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `Legacy MEX infrastructure is provided for compatibility; it will be removed in a future version of MATLAB.` just means that the way of setting up MEX with `mexopts.bat` (Windows) and `mexopts.sh` (*NIX and MAC) is deprecated and an XML based configuration system ("infrastructure" in their words) will be used going forward.  Note that it is not removed yet, just deprecated - you can continue to configure with `mexopts.bat` but it will bug you about it.

For some suggestions on how to make your own XML, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435218/2778484), just to get started.  You will have to do some trial and answer since the intuitive Makefile-like organization of mexopts.bat is gone and replaced with a more complicated system involving automated searches, environment variable reads, etc.